# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location of an Integer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

It seems normally people receive these errors when working with pointers, array, structs, etc.  I'm getting it on every integer in a class, which confuses me.  I'm sure I'm just missing some small technical detail (I'm a bit new to this).

The exact error is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x003e6616 in Mine.exe: 0xC0000005:
    Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
Unhandled exception at 0x003e6616 in Mine.exe: 0xC0000005:
    Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
```

The code breaks at the first line in this class method:

```
void Grid::Move(int x, int y)
{
this->offX+=x;
this->offY+=y;
for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    for (int k=0;k<2;k++)
        BitmapSetxy(chunks[i][k]->map,this->offX,this->offY);
}
```

Here is the constructor of Grid:

```
Grid::Grid()
{
totalW =320*2;
totalH = 320*2;
offX = 0;
offY = 0;

//Fill the chunks array with Maps to be used
for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    for (int k=0;k<2;k++)
        chunks[i][k] = new Map(i*320,k*320);

//Everything starts as dirt
for (int x=0;x<(320*2)/20;x++)
    for (int y=0;y<(320*2)/20;y++)
        blocks[x][y] = bType::Dirt; 
}
```

And the header file:

```
#ifndef MapDef
#define MapDef

#include "Map.h"

class Grid
{
private:
int totalW, totalH;
int offX, offY; 
public:
enum bType
{
    Blank,
    Dirt,
    Copper
};

Map * chunks[2][2];
bType blocks[32][48];   
void RemoveBlock(int x, int y);
bType GetBlockAt(int x, int y);
int GetAbsolutePosition20(int);
int GetMapIndex(int);
int GetChunkRelative(int,int);
bType GetBlockBelow(int x, int y);
bType GetBlockAbove(int x, int y);
bType GetBlockSide(int x, int y, bool isRight);
void Move(int x, int y);
Grid();
};

#endif
```

---

When looking at the locals view of the current instance of Grid totalW, totalH, offX,offY all show the CXX0030 error, but the two arrays are perfectly fine. What exactly is going on here?

EDIT:

The definition of the grid pointer is stored in a separate little namespace that serves as something of a static class:

```
namespace Engine
{       
static Grid * grid;
static Player * player;
}
```

It is actually created here in the main cpp file:

```
//Initialize engine
Engine::grid = new Grid();
Engine::player = new Player(160,240);
```

Here is the excerpt where it is called, in another class called Player

```
    if (y>392 && y<480 && x>75 && x<152)
    {
        printf("Right");
        Engine::grid->Move(20,0);
    }
```

Edit 2:

I'm sorry, I forgot to remove the "static" keyword from the grid declaration in engine.  I believe that was what was causing the problem.

Comment: What is the call stack of the crash? Can you show the code that calls Move?

Comment: by the way, it is 0x00000008 because between the beginning of the class and offX there are 2 ints. If someone was wondering...

Comment: It surely looks as though you have a null pointer for `this`; the access at 0x00000008 is correct for adding 8 bytes to 0 to read the current value of `this->offX` before adding to it.

Comment: I'm getting objects already defined problems, but the original problem is solved.  thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the error message, your code is trying to access address 0x00000008, which is very close to 0.  This means you probably have a null pointer of type `Grid *` somewhere and you are calling a function on it.

You should either ensure that the pointer is not null, or check it.  For example:

```
Grid * grid = ...;
if (grid == NULL){ return; }
grid->move(0,1);
```

Note that `NULL` is the same as 0.

Comment: Heh, thanks for that first sentence, reminded me of how to identify nullpointer dereferencing very fast. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Xeo - how does one identify nullpointer dereferencing quickly? Is it by seeing if the address is close to 0, and if thats the case, why does that work?

Comment: If you see that your program is trying to access an address very close to 0, such as 0x8, then you probably have a null pointer.    In this case, 8 is probably the offset that the compiler chose for the offX member of the Grid class.  So when the compiler wants to access the offX member of a null `Grid *` pointer, it would try to access address 0x8.

Answer (score 3):

What is the value of 'this'? Are you trying to dereference a null pointer to an instance of Grid?